# if statement in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I've got a question about the if statement in VHDL, see the example bellow;-)

```
   signal SEQ : bit_vector(5 downto 0); 
signal output: bit; 
    -------

     if(SEQ = "000001") and (CNT_RESULT = "111111") then 
       output<= '1';
      CNT_RESET <= '0';
      else output<='0';
    end if;
```

and I get : the if statment is illegal and that "output" has multiply sources. any ideas

Comment: The given code compiled with no errors, so probably you should provide more info about process and output signal usage

Answer (score 5):

I presume the `if` statement is not inside a process? You can only use `if` statements inside a process. For similar functionality outside a process, you can use `when`:

```
output <= '1' when (SEQ = "000001") and (CNT_RESULT = "111111") else
          '0';

CNT_RESET <= '0' when (SEQ = "000001") and (CNT_RESULT = "111111") else
             '1';
```

Comment: well the if statement is the a process , and when I tried ur suggestion I've got : unexpected WHEN, expecting SEMICOLON.

Comment: You probably have a syntax fault in a previous line then. Without the rest of the code it's not easy to say where though.

Comment: You can just edit your original question, and add the important bits to it. Just the actual process where your problem happens should be enough, and possibly the declarations of the signals it uses.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using an IF statement in the architecture body (which is a concurrent region). That's illegal. You need to put a process around it, so that it is in a sequential region (code is not tested!):

```
  process(seq, CNT_RESULT)
     if(SEQ = "000001") and (CNT_RESULT = "111111") then 
       output<= '1';
      CNT_RESET <= '0';
      else output<='0';
    end if;
  end process;
```