# what is the equivalent of logical and (&&) in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl

what is the equivalent for && in vhdl in an if statement?

```
otherwise: if (i/=0 && i/=15)  generate
...
end generate;
```

I need to meet two prerequisites.

Comment: And. See example in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062518/if-statement-in-vhdlions/10062518/if-statement-in-vhdl)

Comment: @MichelBillaud That question has been deleted. :(

Comment: Besides a simple syntax issue you don't need *[to meet two prerequisites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8apjO.jpg)*. This works by lengthening the array you originally called wire by one, assigning the first value from c_in and assigning the last value to c_out. There are places you can find [VHDL Online Help](http://vhdl.renerta.com/mobile/index.html) with syntax.

Comment: Relational operators (`/=`) return a boolean and VHDL has predefined operator overloads for boolean types for the `and` operator that returns a boolean. The operators here are found in library `std` package standard subject to implicitly declared library and use clauses (IEEE Std 1076-2008 13.2 Design libraries). At one time the IEEE provided an earlier revision of the standard in HTML ([Language Reference Manual](http://rti.etf.bg.ac.rs/rti/ri5rvl/tutorial/TUTORIAL/IEEE/HTML/1076_TOC.HTM)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question of what is the equivalent of logical and (&&) in VHDL doesn't really make sense, because of VHDL's strong typing. The short answer to your question is that you need:

```
otherwise: if (i/=0) and (i/=15)  generate
...
end generate;
```

but the `and` in that example is no different to the `and` operator in this example:

```
signal F, A, B: boolean;
...
F <= A and B;
```

because the `/=` operator returns the type `boolean`. Therefore, in both examples, I am just `and`ing two booleans together. The return type in both examples will also be of type `boolean`. The type that the `if` statement expects is `boolean`, which is why the first example works.