# Comparison two signed signal

Tags: vhdl

I want to compare two signals. But when I compile my code I get "Illegal concurrent statement" error. How can I compare two signals?

```
Library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_Logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity compare is
end entity;

architecture RTL of compare is

  signal a : signed (7 downto 0);
  signal b : signed (7 downto 0);
  signal c : std_logic;

begin
  if a>b then
    c <= '1';
  end if;

end RTL;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if statement in VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062518/if-statement-in-vhdl)

Answer (score 1):

`if`.. `then` (the *sequential conditional statement*) is only valid within a process in VHDL.

If you want a concurrent statement, you can use a *conditional signal assignment* instead:

```
c <= '1' when a > b else '0';
```